# How to use ganglia ui with flume?

Tags: flume, ganglia

I am interested in monitoring my multi-agent apache flume setup. I have enabled the inbuilt ganglia server which provides me the flume metrics through JSON data. Now I am interested in viewing these info in graphs/charts. TO achieve this I am using ganglia web ui, I have these questions - Do I have to install gmond and gmetad to achieve it, if not then how I will use the existing ganglia info with the ganglia web ui ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need both, IMHO. Moreover, I think Flume can communicate directly to a gmond by appending some stuff in JAVA_OPTS, [see hortonworks docs](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.5.0/bk_installing_manually_book/content/ch_flume-config.html).

You'll need gmetad because it stores your data in RRD files, and the web UI query on it to display graphs.

[Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/) can do the job too.